# What is the "else" clause best practice to use with different variables?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I wish to know what is the best practice to follow when we have conditional clauses which is related to different variables.

For example, in Javascript, considering these following variables

```
var p1 = 'string1'
var p2 = 'string2'
```

And these following functions

```
function xpto1 (p1, p2) {
    if (p1 === 'string1') {
        return true
    } else if (p2 === 'string2') {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

```
function xpto2 (p1, p2) {
    if (p1 === 'string1') {
        return true
    } else {
        if (p2 === 'string2') {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

I know `xpto1` produces the same result as `xpto2`, and I have already used these two logics while coding, but I wish to know: there is a general rule of which of theese two codes is the best? Is it appropriate to create a "else" statement with conditionals inside it (like `xpto2`) always when we have different variables?

Comment: This is a matter of stylistic preference. Personally I do not like using `else` at all when the `if` block always ends with `return`.

Comment: Indentation hurts readability, so the second example is objectively worse than the first

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate what I already said in a comment, I would avoid `else` entirely when the preceding `if` block always returns from the function:

```
function xpto1 (p1, p2) {
    if (p1 === 'string1')
        return true;

    if (p2 === 'string2')
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Clearly the first two predicates can be combined without becoming cumbersome in this case:

```
function xpto1(p1, p2) {
  return p1 === 'string1' || p2 === 'string2';
}
```

which will return `true` or `false` as before, because the `===` comparisons result in a boolean value.

Answer (score -1):

In your example basically the same `{}` pair in javascript (and most languages ​​that use it) is called a `block` if your statement depends has only one line you can remove it ( except for `function`, `const`, `let` ):

```js
function xpto2 (p1, p2) {
    if (p1 === 'string1') {
        return true
    } else {
        if (p2 === 'string2') {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

exact

```
function xpto2 (p1, p2) {
    if (p1 === 'string1') {
        return true
    } else // only one dependent statement
        if (p2 === 'string2') {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    
}
```

after format it returns code 1

only difference if you have 2 statements in `else`

Answer (score -1):

A good code is also easily readable, so you can simplify by removing the last else statement:

```js
function xpto1 (p1, p2) {
    if (p1 === 'string1') {
        return true
    } else if (p2 === 'string2') {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

(the same goes for xpto2)

In any case, ask yourself "is my code understandable and readable?".
The answer is, the less nesting you use, the better.

Answer (score -1):

As you said, there is nothing wrong with the way you are approaching, and which kind of conditions you pick is often depends on the logic, for example if you have a simple condition that returns one value if true and another value if false, you can use the ternary operator, maybe not the best choice for your example,

```js
function xpto2 (p1, p2) {
    return p1 === 'string1' ? true : p2 === 'string2' ? true : false;
}
```

As it might make the code harder to read. For if/else you can probably modify your example to something like this:

```js
function checkP1(p1) {
    return p1 === 'string1';
}

function checkP2(p2) {
    return p2 === 'string2';
}

function xpto3 (p1, p2) {
    if (checkP1(p1)) {
        return true;
    } else if (checkP2(p2)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This way you can have a bit less of nested if/else in place. The other alternative could be a switch statement:

```js
function xpto1 (p1, p2) {
    switch (true) {
        case p1 === 'string1':
            return true;
        case p2 === 'string2':
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Like other answers say, readibility is your best bet, instead of:

```
function xpto2 (p1, p2) {
    if (p1 === 'string1') {
        return true
    } else {
        if (p2 === 'string2') {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

You can always do:

```
function xpto2 (p1, p2) {
    return (p1 === 'string1')?true:(p2 === 'string2');
}
```

The best "if" is the one that can be avoided.

After saying that, you can avoid the else, when a return is "triggered" so:

```
function xpto2 (p1, p2) {
    if (p1 === 'string1') {
        return true
    } 
    if (p2 === 'string2') {
       return true
    } 
    return false
    
}
```

Has the same result.